# $y=\frac{(e^x - e^{-x})}{2}$. Solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The solution is eluding me completely.

My attempt at a solution:
Realize that$ y=e^{\ln(y)}$.
Thus $e^x - e^{-x} = e^{\ln(y)}$
But this gets me nowhere.

Comment: With some practice MathJax doesn't take any longer than trying to make things readable without.

Comment: Hint. Set $e^x=w$ and you get $w^2-2yw-1=0$, which is quadratic.

Comment: do you mean $y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$?

Comment: If you have a half-way decent scientific calculator, hit the keys for inverse hyperbolic sine...

Comment: "$\ y=e^{\ln x}\ $" is false.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Thank you for that hint. Unfortunately, I flagged your comment by mistake and am unable to un-flag it.

Comment: @moonman239 you are welcome! I see you surely got the feedback you asked for!

Answer (score 11):

multply by $e^x$ to give $$e^{2x} - 1 = 2ye^x \implies (e^x)^2 - 2y (e^x) - 1 = 0 \implies e^x = \frac{2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2 +4}}{2} = y \pm \sqrt{y^2+1}.$$ Since $e^x > 0$, we need to take the positive half of $\pm$. Then $$x = \log\left(y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1} \right).$$

Comment: a/k/a  $ \ \sinh^{-1} y \ $ ...

Comment: Yes of course. I assume the OP is asking for an alternative expression for $\text{arcsinh}$. That is, I think the answer $$\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2} = y \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, \sinh(x) = y \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, y = \text{arcsinh}(x)$$ is not the desired response.

Comment: i wasn't offering a criticism of any sort -- it isn't clear to me what the context of the post is.  I just thought I would mention that this inversion is so widely used that it is a named function.

Comment: Sure. I agree: it is worth it to point that out.

Comment: @User8128 Nice derivation of $\operatorname{arcsinh}$!

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, almost anything in the world has a name and is probably also "widely" used by "certain" groups. Names don't tell/teach you anything, they might only help you looking up already discovered things. (Not criticism towards your first post. I found it necessary and very useful for moonman239, because things don't and should not be reinvented or named several times, but I guess you know that.)

Answer (score 3):

Nikolaus provided an excellent hint.

Let w=$e^x$. Thus,

$w + 1/w = y$

Multiplying both sides by w, we get:

$w^2 + 1 = yw$

Thus,

$w^2 - yw + 1 = 0$
$w^2 - yw = -1$
$w^2 - yw + y^2 / 4 = -1 + y^2 / 4$

Comment: There are two large mistakes here. When you multiply by $w$, you should get $w^2 + 1 = yw$ not $w^2 +2w = yw$. Next, even if the preceding work was correct, $w^2 = (2y-2)w$ does not imply $w = \pm (2y-2)$. Indeed, $w^2 = (2y-2)w$ implies that $w = 0$ or $w = 2y-2$.